# The variable ArrayList cannot be resolved

Tags: java, html, jsp, arraylist

What i'm doing wrong? Anyone can help?
at the "if(result.get(0)...)" it says "result cannot be resolved."
I'm stuck on this.

```
<%
    if(session != null){
        ArrayList<Prize> result = new ArrayList<Prize>();
        result = (ArrayList<Prize>) session.getAttribute("result");  
    }
%>

<%
    if(result.get(0).getIdPrize() != null){
        prize = result.get(0);
        out.println(prize.getLottery(prize.getIdLottery()) + 
        " - " + prize.getHour(prize.getIdHour()) +
        " - " + prize.getDate(prize.getDatePrize()));
    }
%>
```

Comment: result is declared in the if statement, and no more visible after the if

Comment: you can move the second if statement inside of the first to make it work correctly. Probably the simplest fix.

Comment: if I declare result outside the error continues...

Comment: moving the second if continues the error too.

Comment: And the cast above it's warning "unchecked cast"

Answer (score 1):

The variable result is declared in the first if block, and no more visible after

Try something

```
    <%
    ArrayList<Prize> result = new ArrayList<Prize>();
    if(session != null){
        result = (ArrayList<Prize>) session.getAttribute("result");  
    }
    %>

<%
    if(result.size() > 0 && result.get(0).getIdPrize() != null){
        prize = result.get(0);
        out.println(prize.getLottery(prize.getIdLottery()) + 
        " - " + prize.getHour(prize.getIdHour()) +
        " - " + prize.getDate(prize.getDatePrize()));
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Vyncent said, move your result declaration outside the if structure.

Answer (score 0):

A common newbiew mistake is not knowing the scope of your variables.
Whatever are in the brackets that will be the cicle of life of your variable

```
    {
     int a = 3; // You can use this variable inside this brackets
      System.out.println(a);
    }
    System.out.println(a); => Java Compiler will throw an error.
```

This is for all if/while/for statements. 
So for solution just know how to use the scope of your variables

```
   ArrayList<Prize> result = new ArrayList<Prize>(); 
        if(session != null){
            result = (ArrayList<Prize>) session.getAttribute("result"); 
        }

    if(result.get(0).getIdPrize() != null){
        prize = result.get(0);
        out.println(prize.getLottery(prize.getIdLottery()) + 
        " - " + prize.getHour(prize.getIdHour()) +
        " - " + prize.getDate(prize.getDatePrize()));
    }
```